# How to ignore field on @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, blob

I have two Entities, the first having a list of the second mapped as @OneToMany.

The question is, that second entity have some info about a file and a BLOB field with the file, i need to get the file info from the second entity but i don't want to get the BLOB because that would be too heavy.

Is there a way to hide the BLOB field for the automatic find of the @OneToMany while i still could persist it as a normal field when needed?

Comment: Since you can't make blob lazy without bytecode instrumentation I wouldn't add blob to entity class.

Comment: Plenty of discussion. https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+lazy+blob&oq=hibernate+lazy+blob&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l4j69i60.3949j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You could mark your BLOB field to be lazy loading by applying the next annotation:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Lazy loading individual fields requires byte code instrumentation i.e. the above annotation on its own will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` but if session is closed and you want to fetch the Blob, it wont work. So to initialize lazy object you need to use `Hibernate.initalize()` with `@Transactional` annotation.And you can get blob outside of transaction as well.